# Retry Mechanism for HTTP Triggered Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

I have been working on leveraging HTTP triggered Azure functions for automations in my project. But there are cases where the Azure function fails because of network issues and other reasons.

My question is, is it sufficient enough to add a try-catch block in my function to cover such failures, or is there any other way we need to ensure that failed executions are retried.

Answer (score 1):

**If requests `from` your Azure Function fail,** a `try/catch` block would be the way to go.

**If requests `to` your Azure Function fail,** then you could either setup a retry in your client.

Or leverage something like [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) if you would want to prevent multiple invocations for the same request. This would be especially useful if there are intensive actions that are best no repeated.